Xvid MiniConvert Error: Source file not supported
I installed Xvid-1.3.7-20191228 on Windows 11 Home.
When, I tried to convert .mp4 file; error message was displayed by "Xvid MiniConvert". "Error: Source file not supported."
What could be the cause of the error?


Probably you don't have the required codec installed.

Which coded needs to be installed?

MP4 is a container. It can have different codecs inside. The program you're using likely needs additional codecs installed system-wide to support what you want to convert. Please note that it playing fine in VLC means nothing. VLC (and Kodi Media Center) uses its own set of codecs that cover most needs but are internal to VLC, i.e., can't be used by other apps. Arguably your best bet is to install a codecs pack like K-Lite.
